# Why is $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1 + x^t} \mathop{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\pi/t}{\sin(\pi/t)}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I don't know how to show $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1 + x^t} \mathop{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\pi/t}{\sin(\pi/t)} $$ for $t > 1$. I guess I'm supposed to use properties of gamma function and Euler's reflection formula.
(I'm sorry if it turns out to be trivial -- I'm not a math student.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the varible $u=\frac{1}{1+x^t}$ and then using the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1 + x^t} \mathop{\mathrm{d}x}\\
&=&\frac1t\int_0^1u^{(1-\frac1t)-1}(1-u)^{\frac1t-1}du\\
&=&\frac1tB(1-\frac1t,\frac1t)\\
&=&\frac1t\frac{\Gamma(1-\frac1t)\Gamma(\frac1t)}{\Gamma(1)}\\
&=&\frac1t\frac\pi{\sin(\frac{\pi}{t})}\\
&=&\frac{\pi/t}{\sin(\pi/t)}.
\end{eqnarray}